# Deploying local Visual Studio build on mac and testing on ipad

Tags: ios, angularjs, visual-studio, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am looking for a means to test my local visual studio build on ipad. 
Currently we have to deploy the build to our dev environment and then test it on the ipad. Is there a way to deploy my local build on mac and run it on the ipad?

Else, is there a add on for Visual Studio 2015 which has a simulator for ipad?
This is for a Single Page App using ANgularjs.

Thanks,
SDD

Answer (score 0):

The alpha version of Xamarin includes support for viewing the iOS simulator directly from the PC, as well as deploying builds to devices using the PC usb port.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/windows/ios-simulator/